# ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from 'flask_login'

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, importerror, flask-login

**i referd miguel flask mega tutorial**
**but i have struggle with an import error issue please help to how to solving this error**

****init**.py**

```
 from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_login import app
#from app.routes import flask_login
from flask_login import microblog

##login function recuring

#login = LoginManager(app)
login.login_view = 'login'
app = Flask(__name__)
login = LoginManager(app)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
from app import routes,models
```

**microblog.py**

```
from app import app,db

from app.models import User, Post

from app import flask_login



@app.shell_context_processor
def make_shell_context():
    return {'db': db, 'User': User, 'Post': Post}
```

**error**

C:\Users\WELCOME\PycharmProjects\microblog>flask shell
Usage: flask shell [OPTIONS]

Error: While importing "app", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\welcome\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
**import**(module_name)
File "C:\Users\WELCOME\PycharmProjects\microblog\app_*init*_.py", line 6, in 
from flask_login import app
ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from 'flask_login' (c:\users\welcome\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\flask_login_*init*_.py)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To get an even better response to future questions, remember to show you effort. What is your understanding of the issue? What have you tried to resolve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

You are importing a namespace that does not exist on your lib `flask_login`. The fault is in the line

```
from flask_login import app
```

Your `app` is defined in the following line

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

Notice that the following line is faulty as well, because you are trying to import once again a namespace that is not defined by the lib

```
from flask_login import microblog
```

If you wish to learn what are the exported names from the `flask_login` lib, check out [their documentation](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or their [`__init__.py` file on github](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/main/flask_login/__init__.py).